# Convert a numeric value to a time in R

Tags: r

I have been given a file with time, in minutes.seconds, in the following format:

```
TimeInput <- c(13.66, 14.08, 12.86)
```

How do I convert a numeric value, for example 13.66, to minutes:seconds format Specifically, 14:06 or 14 minutes and 6 seconds?

My anticipated output would be:

```
TimeInput <- c(14:06, 14:08, 13:26)
```

Comment: Suppose you have values like `13.25`, does it means 250 or 25.  Also, I am assuming that the values will not go greater than 99 ie. 12.99 ?

Comment: It means 25 and the values don't go higher than 99 or 12.99. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Okay, in that case, the solution I posted should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try without using any external package

```
v1 <- (TimeInput-floor(TimeInput)) - 0.60
v2 <- ifelse(v1 > 0, floor(TimeInput) + 1 + v1, TimeInput)
d1 <- data.frame(MinSec = sub(".", ":", v2, fixed = TRUE), 
           TimeRound = floor(v2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d1
#  MinSec TimeRound
#1  14:06        14
#2  14:08        14
#3  13:26        13
```

Comment: Excellent, this worked perfectly. Apologies for asking another question, but how would I create another column that rounds to the nearest minute. For example, `TimeRound <- c(14, 14, 13)`

Comment: @user2716568  updated the post.  It can be either `floor` or `ceiling` based on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the `POSIX.ct` and format

```
TimeInput <- c(13.66, 14.08, 12.86,0)
pct <- as.POSIXct(TimeInput*60,origin = "1960-01-01 00:00:00","GMT")
format(pct,format="%M:%S")
[1] "13:40" "14:05" "12:52" "00:00"
```

The solution is a bit annoying due to timezone/ having to set an arbitrary origin. On the positive side it will deal with all kinds of problem(?) like overflows. **If this is intended**

If you, however, do want to have minutes higher then 60

Answer (score 0):

We can also use functions from `lubridate` package

```
library(lubridate)
timeFormt <- ms(TimeInput)
seconds_to_period(minute(timeFormt) * 60 + second(timeFormt))

#[1] "14M 6S"  "14M 8S"  "13M 26S"
```